# .net application crashes unless renamed

Tags: .net, crash

I have .Net application developed with C#, using C++ library, running on 64-bit Windows 7 OS but in 32 bit mode. Everything was fine until recently I started migration of this application to 64-bit mode. During work on this I returned to my 32-bit original version and now it does not work. When launching it crashes after several seconds barely opening dialog box notifying something about uder-defined breakpoint and then completely disappears on its own. What interesting is that when I just rename the application's executable (e.g. App.exe to App_.exe) it is working fine. It is really weird situation as I do not changed anything but name of the executable. I have a feeling there is some registration somewhere in Framework which causes a problem.I checked Event Logger and say this:

Faulting application name: MyApp.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5310c171
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18229, time stamp: 0x51fb1072
Exception code: 0x80000003
Fault offset: 0x0001000c
Faulting process id: 0x%9
Faulting application start time: 0x%10
Faulting application path: %11
Faulting module path: %12

Please help me with this.

Comment: Can you debug into the application and see why the crash is occuring?

Comment: I tried but it did not work. I turned on all types of Exceptions in VS2008 but it did not help.

Comment: Did you turn off just my code execution?  Also try attaching with both native and managed debugging

Comment: This is what I get after it crashes:

Comment: 'MyApp.exe' (Managed): Loaded '3x1zhew6'
The program '[18916] MyApp.exe: Managed' has exited with code -2147483645 (0x80000003).

Comment: It is a breakpoint exception.  Don't ignore JaredPar's comment.  The name of the file does matter, you obfuscated it too much to have an idea if it matters.  If the .exe name is foobar.exe then make sure that there isn't also a foobar.dll

Comment: I do not have dll with the same name. Also I am able to debug both managed and unmanaged code in all libraries uploaded into this process

Comment: It is interesting. The executable with original name did not start because it was defined in AppVerifier tool. Once I removed it from there I could start running it again

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while since your post, but I just ran into the same problem and found a solution :

I removed the key corresponding to the app in the registry :

\HK_LOCAL_MACIHNE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\**[App.exe]**

Hope it helps

Comment: I had same problem with C++ aplication. Deleting registry helps. Thanks Gus